# Chagas disease: stages

Tags: disease

As far as I understand the stages of Chagas disease are three: *acute*, *indeterminate* and *cronic*.

**Question**

Supposing someone is on third stage, does it mean that he/she has previously go through indeterminate stage?

In other words: Is indeterminate stage a necessary condition to cronic stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an answer. Everybody is invited to debate. The person who wrote it is a Chagas disease specialist, Dr Anis Rassi Jr. So thanks Dr Rassi for the answer.

> The phases of the disease are only 2: acute and chronic. The chronic
>   phase is divided into: indeterminate form, cardiac form, digestive
>   form and cardio-digestive form. With the exception of only about 5% of
>   the patients who right after the acute phase get directly into a
>   determinate form, all the others get into the indeterminate form. Of
>   those in the indeterminate form, about 60% will remain indeterminate
>   all lifelong while about 40% of patients 10 to 30 years later develop
>   the clinical forms of the disease.

Similar information can be read [on this excellent paper](https://scholar.google.com.ar/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Chagas%20disease%20Rassi%2C%20Anis%20et%20al.&btnG=) which is free (and has more than 1300 citations).